# Copying a Range of Cells using Empty Cells as Parameters -> PasteSpecial New Worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

My data is all in one column and grows downward. There are only a few rows of data and then blank spaces ( the # of blank spaces varies ).

I'm trying to select each group of data and transpose it automatically onto the next sheet in the next available row, and continue until there is no more data in the column.

Please forgive my ignorance of the below, I pieced it together from many hours of googling and searching this site.

Here is what I have so far, and it kind of works… but I think I need another integer to be defined, so I can get a range to copy, like

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range(A & I “:” A & X ).Copy
```

Then, a similair operation to paste:

```
Sheets("Sheet2").End(xlUp).Row.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
False, Transpose:=True
```

Complete Macro I'm working with:

```
Sub PadOut()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
j = 1
   'loops from 1 to the last filled cell in column 1 or "A"
    For i = 1 To Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
       'checks if the cell has anything in it
        If IsEmpty(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i)) = False Then
            'this is where the copying and pasting happens (well basically)
            Sheets("Sheet1").Range(A & i).copy
            Sheets("Sheet2").End(xlUp).Row).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
            False, Transpose:=True
            j = j + 1
        End If
    Next i

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks guys, I was going back and editing the formatting actually, by the time I was done you all had finished. Thank you!

Comment: Is there any data in column `B`? If not, you might use `CurrentRegion` property (I'll post an answer, if the answer is "yes" :) )

Comment: No data in column B, I want to take the areas of data between blanks in column A and transpose them onto sheet 2, one row per data group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I define a Source range and then using the Range's SpecialCells method I break the Source into Areas.  Next I iterate over the Areas of the Source range and transpose them to the next empty cell on Sheet2.

```
Sub PadOut()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim Source As Range, Target As Range
    Dim i As Long

    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        On Error Resume Next
        Set Source = .Range("A1", .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
        Set Source = Source.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    If Not Source Is Nothing Then
        With Sheets("Sheet2")

            For i = 1 To Source.Areas.Count
                Source.Areas(i).Copy
                Set Target = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)

                If Target.Value = "" Then
                    Target.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True
                Else
                    Target.Offset(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True
                End If
            Next

        End With
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: This works more than anything so far, except it transposes everything on the same row, and seems to add spaces between the groups of data in random places

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Comment: I can't seem to edit this in a way that is helpful... just a moment.

Comment: Are there formulas or blank spaces in your data?

Comment: No formulas, and yes there are a varied amount of blank spaces. I edited your post to show more accurately.

Comment: The current code will transpose the data in the column perfectly, except it won't put each group of data on a new line

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the data?

Comment: I fixed the Code.  When I used Union to join the cells with  Constants and the cells with Formulas the Areas were merged one.

Comment: Awesome, absolutely awesome. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The code would to be like this.

```
Sub PadOut()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim i As Long
Dim n As Long
n = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

   'loops from 1 to the last filled cell in column 1 or "A"

    For i = 1 To n
       'checks if the cell has anything in it
        If IsEmpty(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i)) = False Then
            'this is where the copying and pasting happens (well basically)
            Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i).Copy Sheets("Sheet2").Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2)
        End If
    Next i

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Would I put the .PasteSpecial code after the .End(xlUp)(2)?

Answer (score 0):

Function to skip blank cells will be useful in your case:

```
Function SkipBlanks(start As Range) As Long
Dim r, c As Long
r = start.Row
c = start.Column
'we make sure, that we won't exceed the number of rows
Do While IsEmpty(Cells(r, c)) And r < Rows.Count
    r = r + 1
Loop

SkipBlanks = r

End Function
```

It takes cell as parameter, and looks for next non-empty cell. If given cell is not empty, it will return its row, if it is empty, the function will return row of next non-empty cell. Using that function, we can write the following:

```
Sub s()
Dim startingRow, i, j As Long
j = 3
i = 1

'we will through all rows
Do While i < Rows.Count
    'we skip  blanks
    startingRow = SkipBlanks(Cells(i, 1))
    i = startingRow

    Do While Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, 1))
        Cells(i - startingRow + 1, j).Value = Cells(i, 1).Value
        i = i + 1
    Loop

    'we move to next column (here you can place code, which will choose next sheet to use
    j = j + 1

Loop
End Sub
```

This subroutine takes first block of data, puts it in C column, then skips blanks until next block of data and puts it in D column, etc. Instead of going to another column, you can go as well to another sheet.